# What does the series $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}e^{i \pi n x}$ ($n\neq 0)$ converges to on $(-1,1)$?

Tags: uniform-convergence

What does the series $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}e^{i \pi n x}$ ($n\neq 0)$ converges to on $(-1,1)$? I tired plotting this series for different values of $n$ and it seemed it is zero everywhere, which I know it cannot be true. Moreover, I know it converges because $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is finite.

Comment: Could you expand a little on the convergence of the series? For $x=0$ the series only converges as a "principal value".

Comment: $e^{i\pi n}=\cos(\pi n)+i\sin(\pi n)=\cos(\pi n)$